# A graphical representation of client and server connections on a website after fetching connection details from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data for some servers and clients. The clients are using some shares from different servers. Now let the data be in the following format.

```
Client   Share         Server
C1       Share S1A       S1
C1       Share S1B       S1
C2       Share S1B       S1
C2       Share S2B       S2
C2       Share S2A       S2
C3       Share S2B       S2
```

Now the above data i have in a table in MySql and i have a PHP based website. I want a graphical representation on my website showing the connections between the clients and the servers.  Now this table can change and the representation should be dynamic.

Each connection from client to server should show a list of shares concerned. Like the line connected between C1 and S1 if clicked should show me a tab or box or hover toolbox listing Share S1A, Share S1B.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a way to make a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) in PHP. You might get better answers if you asked that more general question.